# Migration of EJB 2.1 to 3.1

Tags: ejb, ejb-3.1, ibm-rad

I would like to check if there’s any standard procedures for migration from EJB 2.1 to 3.1 on the Rational Application Developer for WebSphere Software?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question. Are you asking if you can convert XML-based 2.x EJBs into annotations-based 3.x EJBs? If that's the question then the answer is no (that I'm aware).

If instead you want to upgrade from 2.x to 3.x level you can use the Java EE Specification Upgrade wizard. For this, right click on the project you want to upgrade (recommended is selecting the EAR which will migrate the whole thing) and select *Java EE* > *Specifications Upgrade Wizard*. This will not use the annotation approach introduced in EJB 3.x, but will upgrade the XML files to the selected version.